# Aligning misaligned column using python

Tags: python, pandas, file, text-files

Data to be extracted

[image: Data]

Data misalignment after 999 rows (It can occur at many places when digits adds as data would exceed 10k)

[image: Misalignment]

```
data = pd.read_fwf("copy.txt",index=False,sep='\t', names=["A", "B", "C"])
```

Objective: First column should be discared. So

1. Padding with spaces for columns then dicard it
2. Inserting dummy column in between (so that it does not corrupt my
   data in next column)

   data["A"]= data["A"].astype(str).str.pad(15, side ='right', fillchar =' ')

[image: Padding]

Second option:

```
data.insert(1, "Dummy", "Any")
```

[image: Inserting]

```
data['A'] = data['A'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```

It didn't help me either

Objective was to discard the first column(those are not indexes) and name it with header 
This is result text required. Is there any way to align or discard first column without corrupting data ?

[image: Result required]

Comment: You're using the wrong reader. Specifying `sep` in a fixed-width-file makes no sense. I'm surprised it even allows that without a warning. The data likely aren't mis-aligned, you just have a tab delimiter. Do `pd.read_csv('copy.txt', index=False, sep='\t', names=["A", "B", "C"])` so that you use the `csv_reader` as your file is not fixed-width.

Comment: @ALollz Thanks for the sense of direction Worked